# Ratio Between Non-Square Matrices, Matlab

Tags: matlab

I've run into a problem.

I have these two massive matrices, lets call them A and B for this purpose.

They are not square which is what is causing the main problem. I'm trying to create a matrix that is holds the ratio of A[i,j] / B[i,j].

I had assumed them to be square from the get go, but now i'm kind of at a loss as to how to proceed. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `./` instead of `/` for element-wise division, then `A` and `B` only have to be of the same size, but not necessarily square. If you've been using `A/B`, you've been doing it wrong (as that is approximately `A*inv(B)` as a matrix product).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just trying to get an element-wise ratio of two matrices of the same size, you can do this by using the rdivide operator (./):

```
>> C = A ./ B;
```

There's no need for the matrices to be square, just the same size.  If you had square matrices before and you were doing A / B (this is the mrdivide operator), you were actually calculating A*B^{-1}.

Comment: Love it. Didn't know Matlab had the ability to do that operation.